# Error when implementing gensim.LdaMallet

Tags: python, lda, gensim

I was following the instructions on this link ("http://radimrehurek.com/2014/03/tutorial-on-mallet-in-python/"), however I came across an error when I tried to train the model:

```
    model = models.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus, num_topics =10, id2word = corpus.dictionary)
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\brlu\\appdata\\local\\temp\\c6a13a_state.mallet.gz'
```

Please share any thoughts you might have.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am facing the same right now

Answer (score 3):

This can happen for two reasons:
1. You have space in your mallet path.
2. There is no MALLET_HOME environment variable.

Comment: I have the same problem as the original poster. Mallet is in `C:\Mallet` and the environment variable is `C:\Mallet\` checked from `cmd.exe` with `echo %MALLET_HOME%` Is there something I'm missing or could there be another solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to import gensim's mallet wrapper. The following code resolved the error.

```
import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

os.environ['MALLET_HOME'] = 'C:/.../mallet-2.0.8/'
```

A more detailed explanation can be found here:
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2137

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that mallet **properly** works from command-line.
2. Look to your folder 'c:\users\brlu\appdata\local\temp\...' if there are some files, you can deduce at which step mallet-wrapper fails. Try this step at command line.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems with `gensim` + `MALLET` on Windows:

1. Make sure that `MALLET_HOME` is set
2. Escape slashes when set mallet_path in Python

   ```
   mallet_path = 'c:\\mallet-2.0.7\\bin\\mallet'
   LDA_model = gensim.models.LdaMallet(mallet_path, ...
   ```
3. Also, it might be useful to modify line 142 in `Python\Lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamallet.py:` change `--token-regex '\S+'` to `--token-regex \"\S+\"`

Hope it helps

Answer (score -2):

Try the following

1. *import tempfile*
2. *tempfile.tempdir='some_other_non_system_temp_directory'*